# When doing an Import of an Azure Data Factory V2 ARM template, unexpected characters are added at the top

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm following the Continuous [integration deployment guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) for azure data factory V2, I'm stuck at the Import ARM step, for some reason, after Loading the arm_template.zip I get unexpected characters that cause my json file to fail[image]

Any idea idea on how to avoid these or clean these?

For now I just removed everything before the opening bracket and made sure the JSON was well formed and looks like it worked! however I'm still curious to know why the Import is getting these unexpected characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected characters are actually zip file header.

You need unzip the arm_template.zip yourself and upload arm_template.json file only.